# Is there a better way to access array data in package.json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, package.json

I've got a little snippet of configuration in my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "who-rules-app",
    "config": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "words": [
            "tpr",
            "rules"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node src/index.js"
    }
}
```

From what I can tell, people generally access the `config` key using `process.env['npm_package_${keyname}']`, e.g.:

```
process.env['npm_package_config_foo']
//> "bar"
```

But when the value is an array, you get this ultra-hokey set of flattened, numbered keys:

```
process.env['npm_package_config_words_0']
//> "tpr"
process.env['npm_package_config_words_1']
//> "rules"
```

I could always just read the file off disk using `fs`, but it's my understanding that doing things through `process.env` permits this stuff to interact with environment variables, which is a pretty great way to handle configuration across different environments.

Ideally, I would like:

```
process.env['npm_package_config_words']
//> [ "tpr", "rules" ]
```

Is there a better way? A well-tested module out there? A cool pattern?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: not sure if you really need to have your config inside of the package.json file, but if not, I usually use this library for setting env variables https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using what is basically a process.env hack, any recent version of Node will happily load .json files right out of the box, so simply write something like:

```
let package = require('./package.json');
let config = package.config || {};
let words = config.words || [];
```

And that's all you should need to do.

Comment: Certainly, loading the file directly will work great. But, as I said, I worry about losing whatever interaction with env vars currently happens as part of the `process.env` hack. Are you saying there is none? Or are you suggesting I re-implement that behavior on top of a straight file read?

Comment: Why would there be interaction? You, as programmer, are responsible for which value you use; your runtime environment and your package.json do not affect each other. If you need values from your package.json, load package.json. If you need values from your env, use process.env, and if you need better env control, start using a real environment package like dotenv (which _still_ does not interact with your package.json - your environment has nothing to do with values in your package.json)

Answer (score 1):

I am using [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) package for environment variables.

> Dotenv is a zero-dependency module that loads environment variables
>   from a .env file into process.env

In your config.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

.env file

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

You can use them like

```
const db = require('db')
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
})
```